# Maximize browser in Sencha test

Tags: testing, extjs, webdriver

How can I maximize browser window in Sencha test 2.0.0 when the test is run via WebDriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
it('It should maximize window', function(){
  ST.defaultContext.driver.windowHandleMaximize();
})
```

SenchaTest uses WebDriverIO, so you can use WdIO API as well. In this case, it is [windowHandleMaximize](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/windowHandleMaximize.html).

Look at Sencha Forum - this [post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?330017-Non-MVC-architecture-sencha-test&p=1165261&viewfull=1#post1165261) is very informative.

Comment: Thank you! It is strange that there is no description of defaultContext field in [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/sencha_test/2.0.0/api/ST.html)

BTW windowHandleMaximize() changes browser size but it doesn't fill all the screen

Comment: Yeah, it is good improvement for Sencha, to add it to doc. :) 
And - I tested and it filled all the screen, so, well - I am not familiar if this method has some bugs or not.

Comment: May be it depends on OS and browser version.